# C# Error: The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-errors, var

I have written the following function to create an `axWindowsMediaPlayer` playlist:

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist p2 = axWindowsMediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist 1");

private void CreatePlaylist(string _currentId)
{
  string selectedElementPageTypeValue = MainContentAreaBl.GetSelectedElementPageTypeValue(_currentId);
  var selectedElementJumpToValue = MainContentAreaBl.GetSelectedElementValue(_currentId, "jumpTo");
  if (selectedElementJumpToValue != null)
  {
     _currentId = selectedElementJumpToValue;                
     if (_currentId != null && _currentId != "menu" && selectedElementPageTypeValue == "video")
     {
        var playerFile = Path.Combine(Common.ContentFolderPath, MainContentAreaBl.GetSelectedElementDataPathValue(_currentId));
        p2.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer.newMedia(playerFile));
        axWindowsMediaPlayer.currentPlaylist = p2;
        CreatePlaylist(_currentId);
     }                
     axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
  }
}
```

Here `var p2` is declared at class level. When I compiled my application, i received the following error message:

> The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration

However, I cannot put `var p2 = axWindowsMediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist 1");` inside the recursive function as it will create new playlist on each iteration.

How do I access p2 in my function?

**Edit 1:** I am seeing this in Output Window

> COM Reference 'WMPLib' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxWMPLib' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.

Also, now it shows the following error on `axWindowsMediaplayer`:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property

Does this information has to do anything with the Error that I am seeing? How do go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing the playlist in the **Constructor** and passing the playlist as arguments did the trick as answered by @thumbnumkeys (now removed). Here is the code that worked for me:

```
namespace ABC
{
public partial class MainContentArea : Form
{
    private string _currentId;        

    public MainContentArea(string topicId, Menu menu)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _currentId = topicId;
        _menu = menu;
        WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist p2 = axWindowsMediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist 1");
        CreatePlaylist(_currentId, p2);
    }
private void CreatePlaylist(string _currentId, WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist p2)
{    
   var selectedElementJumpToValue = MainContentAreaBl.GetSelectedElementValue(_currentId, "jumpTo");
   string selectedElementPageTypeValue = MainContentAreaBl.GetSelectedElementPageTypeValue(selectedElementJumpToValue);            
   if (selectedElementJumpToValue != null)
   {
      _currentId = selectedElementJumpToValue;                
      if (_currentId != null && _currentId != "menu" && selectedElementPageTypeValue == "video")
      {
         var playerFile = Path.Combine(Common.ContentFolderPath, MainContentAreaBl.GetSelectedElementDataPathValue(_currentId));                    
         p2.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer.newMedia(playerFile));
         axWindowsMediaPlayer.currentPlaylist = p2;
                CreatePlaylist(_currentId, p2);
      }
            //axWindowsMediaPlayer.BringToFront();
   }
        axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You will have to declare it with the right type instead of using `var`:

```
AxWMPLib.IWMPPlaylist p2 = axWindowsMediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist 1");
```

`var` is only allowed on local variables, not on fields, and that's what the error message tells you. The error message does not mean that the field is declared in the wrong place, you just used the wrong syntax for the field type.

Comment: My application is not accepting IWMPPlaylist as well

Comment: It should because that is the interface type returned by `newPlaylist` though it depends on whether you're using `dynamic` or similar. Can you tell us what it says when you use that interface type?

Comment: Try `WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist`.

Comment: On using `WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist`, I received the following error: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Then you have to move the initialization expression into a constructor. Have you considered doing what @thumbnunkeys have suggested, passing the mediaplayer or playlist to the method as a parameter instead of having it as a field?

Comment: On using `IWMPPlaylist`, I am receiving the following error: "The type or namespace name 'IWMPPlaylist' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Also note that there may be, as you now notice, many things wrong with your code but one question should not be used to answer all of these. I can only answer the question you asked, about `var`, a followup question should be asked as that, a new question.

Comment: How did you declare `axWindowsMediaPlayer`?

Comment: `axWindowsMediaPlayer` is just a component. I simply dragged it on my **WinForm** which generated the following code in designer.cs : `this.axWindowsMediaPlayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();`

Comment: OK, so then try `AxWMPLib.IWMPPlaylist`.

Comment: results in Error : "The type or namespace name 'IWMPPlaylist' does not exist in the namespace 'AxWMPLib' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Then sorry, I cannot help you, you need to find out which type this `newPlaylist` method returns yourself. You still cannot use `var`, you *must* specify an actual type.

Comment: If you hover the mouse over `newPlaylist` it should tell you what it returns, that is the type you should declare the field or parameter as.

Comment: It shows `WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist IWMPPlaylistCollection.newPlaylist(String bstrName)` but doesn't accept `WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist`. It throws this: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property". It throws this error on axWindowsMediaPlayer

Comment: I was about to try the answer given by @thumbnumkeys but it seems to have been deleted. Can you please post that technique as well?

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310867.aspx) says:

> **To correct this error**
>
> If the variable belongs at class scope, give it an explicit type.
>   Otherwise move it inside the method where it will be used.

So you can give the correct type while declaring the type of your variable like

```
IWMPPlaylist p2 = axWindowsMediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist 1");
```

or else you can move the variable inside the method where it is going to be used. In your case, you can move it inside the **CreatePlaylist** method.

Comment: I cannot move it inside the CreatePlaylist method as it is a recursive one.. If I do so then it will create new playlist everytime and not **append** the current list

Comment: On using **IWMPPlaylist**, I am receiving the following error: "The type or namespace name 'IWMPPlaylist' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I know I shouldn't,... but WHY? Why can't the compiler infer the type of class scoped fields?

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned the problem. The specific type you would want is `IWMPPlaylist`, so the full line will look like this.

```
IWMPPlaylist p2 = axWindowsMediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist 1");
```

Comment: On using **IWMPPlaylist**, I am receiving the following error: "The type or namespace name 'IWMPPlaylist' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"